# Django admin: How to get path of uploaded file

Tags: python, django

I have created model field for User Pic and User_pic_url, what i'm trying to do is when i upload image it's path should get populated in user_pic_url.
Note that i'm uploading image from django admin itself. any idea.

snapshot for ref:
[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsubu.png)

Model.py:

```
class Main(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    about = models.TextField()
    contact = models.CharField(default='0', max_length=12)
    email = models.CharField(default='-', max_length=50)
    linkedin = models.CharField(default='-', max_length=50)
    github = models.CharField(default='-', max_length=50)
    site_name = models.CharField(default='-', max_length=50)
    resume = models.FileField()
    cover_letter = models.FileField()
    user_pic = models.ImageField()
    user_pic_url = models.TextField(default="-")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Django documentation regarding [managing files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/#using-files-in-models)

> Consider the following model, using an ImageField to store a photo:
>
> ```
> class Car(models.Model):
>     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
>     price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
>     photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='cars')
> ```
>
> Any Car instance will have a photo attribute that you can use to get
> at the details of the attached photo:
>
> ```
> car = Car.objects.get(name="57 Chevy")
> car.photo
> <ImageFieldFile: cars/chevy.jpg>
> car.photo.name
> 'cars/chevy.jpg'
> car.photo.path
> '/media/cars/chevy.jpg'
>  car.photo.url
> 'http://media.example.com/cars/chevy.jpg'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the uploaded path first make sure you have configure you MEDIA_URL MEDIA_ROOT in settings.py and also you have to put your put url patterns for media url given in the documentation

if you have already done that you have to simply put the query set

```
obj = Main.objects.all().first()
```

like this when you get any object you have to go to the imagefield and add url after that like this
you have to only put url after all the configuration in the imagefield

```
 print(obj.user_pic.url) <---------you can get your url like this
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a ***`user_pic_url`*** field. You can *fetch* the data from the `user_pic` field itself

```
class Main(models.Model):
    # rest of your fields
    user_pic = models.ImageField()

    @property
    def user_pic_url(self):
        return self.user_pic.url
```

Now, you can access the URL directly as,

`model_instance = Main.objects.first()
print(model_instance.user_pic_url)`